# %~dp0 returns truncated file path

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have batch file in directory 'c:/my-folder'.
In the batch file I am setting variable mypath with %~dp0 as follows:

`set mypath="%~dp0"`

the value of mypath variable is truncated and set to "C:\MY-FOL~1" , not "C:\my-folder" as I expect.

If I change the name of the directory where the batch file resides to be without hyphen, i.e'myfolder' instead of 'my-folder' then it works as expected.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Maybe you want to disable 8.3 file names `fsutil behavior set disable8dot3 1`

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1284369/how-to-get-dp0-in-long-name-format

Comment: BTW, if you were to 'disable 8.3 file names' it only prevents the generation of new short file names, it doesn't remove any which already exist.  Also doing so, in some codepages, and with some applications, you could break things. It may also help us to assist you if you were to provide the file system used on the volume your batch file resides.

Comment: I __suppose__ the folder name `my-folder` does not contain the [hyphen-minus](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm) character with code value 2D available in all code pages as being an ASCII character, but a Unicode character just looking like a [hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) like figure dash, en dash, em dash, horizontal bar, minus sign, non-breaking hyphen, etc. The short 8.3 file/folder name is used on file/folder path/name contains a Unicode character which is not available in currently used character encoding.